# How to read Registry display name using nsis

Tags: nsis

Am trying to install multiple instance of same application which i created using the NSIS installer, All i am doing is while installing, i am getting the application description from the user and setting the name of the application with the combination of application name along with description (say: my app (Desc 1) 1.0.0.0). so that each time user install a new version he enters different version and installing new instance. But the problem is no where am storing the description. while uninstalling i can't able to get the description, so that i can't able to delete the registry. Is there any best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy option is to store it in a .ini file next to your uninstaller ($instdir\uninst.ini) and the read it back in the uninstaller ($exedir\uninst.ini) with the NSIS ini functions.

You can also embed the data at the end of the uninstaller.exe (Similar to how [custom installers](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData) can be implemented)